# REST api vs Android HERE WeGo fastest route discrepancy

Tags: here-api

We use your service REST api 7.2v, and your Android HERE WeGo (version 2.0.12509) app in offline mode. Our goal is to be able to create a route using the Routing API - route from A to B (fastest;car) and then send the information to the mobile app.
The expected result would be that from the suggested routes on the mobile app, the first one would be the fastest route, and it will correspond with the one that we created using the api.
The problem: fastest route shown on the HERE WeGo app is not corresponding with the one given from the API call. Also, we noticed that the information for duration and distance that we get from the api, are different on the mobile app for the same route.
Questions: Is it even possible to get the same route results? Are we missing a parameter? Can you give us a suggestion.

Comment: Maybe the call made to the REST API is taking the traffic into account, while the app in offline mode is not. Make sure you have `traffic:disabled` in the *mode* parameter. Most likely there is indeed a difference between both requests.

Comment: This is the call we are using, as you can see traffic is disabled   https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=************&app_code=************&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&routeattributes=sh&maneuverattributes=di,sh&waypoint0=geo!41.99494,21.42115&waypoint1=geo!48.25653368893731,12.6490528605691&alternatives=3

Answer (score 1):

The offline and online algorithms are different and will continue to be different because of the resources available to compute the routes are different on hi-perf servers vs constrained devices. So it is not possible to get the same route results. Also the Here We go app comes in online mode, so the best approach is to get the route directly instead of using REST API and sending it in mobile app.